# Why use model.matrix to build design?

Tags: r

I am a bit confused about the use that we sometimes do of model.matrix. I understand that it is meant to build a design matrix ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix ) but why don't we just stick to passing the columns straight to glm?

I've built a little example to try to find any difference but both seem equivalent. Could anyone explain?

Thanks!

```
## Data prep
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

set.seed(200)
s = 204
dt = data.table(x1=seq(1,s), 
            x2=c(-3,0,3,9), 
            switch = c("Low","Zero","High","VHigh"),
            e = rnorm(s,mean =0, sd=5))

dt[, y_real := x1^2+x2*e]


# Regression without explicit design matrix
r = lm(y_real~I(x1^2)+switch,data=dt)
summary(r)
dt[, y_fitted := r$fitted.values]

# Regression with explicit design matrix
mod = model.matrix(~I(x1^2)+switch+0, data=dt)
r2 = lm(dt$y_real~mod)
summary(r2)
dt[, y_model := r2$fitted.values]

identical(dt$y_fitted, dt$y_model) # => FALSE, but errors ~ 1e-14

ggplot(dt[1:20])+
 aes(x=x1)+
 geom_line(aes(y = y_real, colour = "Y real"))+
 geom_point(aes(y = y_fitted, colour = "Y fitted"))+
 geom_line(aes(y = y_model, colour = "Y model"))
 # => perfectly aligned
```

Comment: What if you have categorical variables? What if you have transform to variables? What if you have interactions? What if you are fitting splines and predict it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using it like this, they are equivalent to each other. From a regression formula and data, you can get a model.matrix, and each column of model.matrix is just the transformed version of original variables according to the formula, and that is everything needed to get the regression parameter.

From my own perspective, I think model.matrix is just a bridge between the formula world (which we use to describe the statistical model) and the numerical methods that glm and lm and other statistical methods actually rely on. From a user point, you only need to know that you have some formula, and you have some data, then you can use lm or glm to get the results you want, which is really easy, and you don't need to care about model.matrix. From the actually implementation perspective, you get the model.matrix from the formula and data, and then you carry on some numerical methods to get the result you want.

And although most users don't need to care about model.matrix, some  users may care about it. Maybe they want to do some analysis on the design matrix?   Maybe they extend the formula class and they want their new "formula" class to generate model.matrix and then can be used by glm or lm directly? Or they develop some new regression methods on matrix (model.matrix) and they can make their regression methods easy to use with formula and data.frame, which is more appealing to the general users?

In my personal view, model.matrix is a potentially useful abstraction which simplifies the life of researchers and developers a lot. Hope it helps.